# Вывод элементов массива с добавлением в конце каждого текста

Tags: python

Предположим у меня есть одномерный массив

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Что нужно сделать чтобы вывелось

```
@1(.) @2(.) @3(.) @4(.) @5(.) @6(.)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

s = ' '.join('@{}(.)'.format(i) for i in a)

print(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно и без for

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

s=' '.join(map('@{}(.)'.format, a))

print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

new = ""
for z in a:
    new = new + '@'+str(z)+'(.)';
print(new)
```

Comment: Это будет работать, но для больших размеров массива очень неэффективно. new будет пересоздаваться на каждой итерации (даже если использовать += , т.к. строки - неизменяемая структура данных). Поэтому ваш код будет иметь квадратичную сложность. Решение на основе метода join позволяет сделать то же самое за линейное время. Ну и плюс вы потеряли пробел, и для него внутрь вашего цикла придётся вкорячивать условие, что итерация не последняя. Решение на основе join позволяет легко обходить и эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если только напечатать, то можно так:

```
print("@", end="")
print(*a, sep="(.) @", end="")
print("(.)")
```

так, для разнообразия... или в одну строчку ))

```
print("@", end=""); print(*a, sep="(.) @", end=""); print("(.)")
```

Никогда так не делайте, но работает ))

Comment: ; не считается за однострочник)

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
for x in a:
    print(f'@{x}(.)', end=' ')
```